# Regarding the styling of a box

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

This is the Box styling I am trying to achieve [Image of the box I want to render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZo0T.png). This is the result[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDUAj.png), with the code snippet[Code for the input box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiCXE.png). I just cannot figure out a way to add inner-shadows on top and left with grey& white and bottom and right.

Can I get some help with code snippet to add inner shadows? Thank you for reading this.

**Edit**
Apologies, the code snippet I attached here was an image. I have it now as text. Please have a look.

```
Container(
          height: 60.0,
          width: 320.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
          ),
          child: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Email',
                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.grey),
                border: InputBorder.none,
                prefixIcon: Icon(
                  Icons.mail,
                  color: Colors.grey[700],
                )),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Do not put your code into an image.. edit your question and add your code as text so we can use it please

Comment: Check this : https://github.com/askNilesh/flutter_groove_buttons

Comment: -LonelyWolf, Sorry my bad. I am new to this platform. I will put it the code as text. Thank you.

Comment: there is a handy package for this use.. I've never try that but it look good... Try it https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_neumorphic#-readme-tab-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified the code to get the effect you want. I added two shadows, white and grey also centered the text in the container.

```
Container(
            height: 60.0,
            width: 320.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey[300],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    spreadRadius: 1,
                    blurRadius: 2,
                    offset: Offset(2, 2),
                  ),
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey[400],
                    spreadRadius: 1,
                    blurRadius: 2,
                    offset: Offset(-2, -2),
                  ),
                ]),
            child: Center(
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Email',
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    color: Colors.grey[500],
                  ),
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.mail,
                    color: Colors.grey[700],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: I will try it out and check if it works. Thank you!

Comment: It works just as I wanted. So thankful for this. Hope I can get some help with some other things too.